# how to arrange and select only 7 high performed subjects

Tags: php

I need to be able be to arrange the subjects according to the marks obtained from high to lowest per each student, the code is

```
            <td>
            <?php
                    // echo $res['subject_marks']." -"
                        $t = $res['subject_marks'];
                         if($t>=75){
                            echo $res['subject_marks']." - A";
                         }else if($t>=65){
                            echo $res['subject_marks']." - B";
                         }else if($t>=45){
                            echo $res['subject_marks']." - C";
                         }else if($t>=30){
                            echo $res['subject_marks']." - D";
                         }else if($t>0){
                            echo $res['subject_marks']." - F";
                         }else if($t<0){
                            echo "";
                         }
                ?> 
            </td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```

the sql query
foreach ($subjects as $subject_result_key => $subject) {

```
    $tbl_student_subject_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student_primary_subject
        -- INNER JOIN tbl_student_registered ON tbl_student_registered.student_id = tbl_student_registered_subject.student_id
        INNER JOIN tbl_primary_subject ON tbl_primary_subject.subject_id = tbl_student_primary_subject.subject_id
        WHERE tbl_student_primary_subject.student_id='$sudentid' ";
    $results = $con->query($tbl_student_subject_query);
    $total_rows = $results->num_rows;
    $subject_marks = "-";
    foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
        if ($result['subject_id'] == $subject['subject_id']) {
            $subject_marks = $result['marks'];
        }
    }
    if ($subject_marks !== "-") {
        $total_marks += $subject_marks;
        $avg_marks    = $total_marks/ $total_rows;
    }
    $subjects_results[$subject_result_key] = [
        'subject_name'  => $subject['subject_name'],
        'subject_code'  => $subject['subject_code'],
        'subject_marks'  => $subject_marks,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Sort the array first with the given criteria then just echo the output

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by a field directly in your SQL query using `ORDER BY` with `ASC` (ascending) or `DESC` (descending).

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE fieldName = 'example' ORDER BY otherFieldName ASC
```

On your code it will affect only the end of your query

```
$tbl_student_subject_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student_primary_subject
    -- INNER JOIN tbl_student_registered ON tbl_student_registered.student_id = tbl_student_registered_subject.student_id
    INNER JOIN tbl_primary_subject ON tbl_primary_subject.subject_id = tbl_student_primary_subject.subject_id
    WHERE tbl_student_primary_subject.student_id='$sudentid' ORDER BY subject_marks DESC";
```

Comment: Thanks, but i tried it doesn't sort the results